# TypeScript passing class into anonymous function

Tags: typescript

I have a question about syntax. I have been looking for the answer for quite a while but without success so sorry if it was already answered here.

I would like to ask how can I call "this" reference inside a class when adding an event listener.  Here's code example to explain it better.

The `myListClass` basically contains `HTMLDivElement`s and I would like to add event listeners

```
        class App {
            private myList: myListClass;

            constructor() {
                this.myList = new myListClass();

                this.myList.getList().forEach(function (element) {

                    element.addEventListener('click', function (this) {
                        let itemType = this.getAttribute('data-item-type');
                        let itemId = this.getAttribute('data-item-id');

                        //dont know how to make this call
                        this(referencing to App class).myFunction(itemType, itemId);

                    }, false);
                });

            }

            public myFunction(itemType, itemId) {
                // do magic
            };
        }
```

Comment: arrow function can probably solve your issue. it retain current context of `this`, so within your callback function, you can use `this.myFunction(itemType, itemId)`

Comment: but I also need to be referencing to the current html element so I can get the data atrributes

Comment: replace this with a param? 

`element.addEventListener('click', (clickedElement) => { let itemType = clickedElement.getAttribute('data-item-type')`

Comment: this.myList.getList().forEach(function (element) { using this here does not reference to the class }   so how would the arrow function look like?

Comment: try replacing your function with arrow function call, like:

`this.myList.getList().forEach(element => {`

Comment: That actually solves all of it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

arrow function is your friend :)

> An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax than a function expression and does not have its own this

When you try to access the original context within your callback function, if you replace the annoymous function `function() {}` with `() => {}`, you can access the original `this` context!

```
class App {
        private myList: myListClass;

        constructor() {
            this.myList = new myListClass();

            this.myList.getList().forEach(element => {

                element.addEventListener('click',  clickEvent => {
                    let itemType = element.getAttribute('data-item-type');
                    let itemId = element.getAttribute('data-item-id');
                    //now it should work!
                    this.myFunction(itemType, itemId);

                }, false);
            });

        }

        public myFunction(itemType, itemId) {
            // do magic
        };
    }
```

read more about arrow function on [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: in this case the "clickedElement" doesnt it actually represent the click event?

Comment: yup it does! let me replace it with element

Comment: You can acutally use the "element" from the first arrow function. So thank you!!